# How can I pass member function of one class as an argument to member function of another class?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

```
class EmulNet
{
    public:
    int ENrecv(Address *myaddr, std::function<int (void*,char*,int)> fn, struct timeval *t, int 
    times, void *queue); 
};

class MP1Node{
    public:
    int recvLoop();
    int enqueueWrapper(void *env, char *buff, int size);
};

int MP1Node::recvLoop() {
    return emulNet->ENrecv(&(memberNode->addr), std::bind(&MP1Node::enqueueWrapper,this), NULL, 1, &(memberNode->mp1q));

}
```

Note - emulNet is an object of class EmulNet

Above code doesn't work.

```
No viable conversion from '__bind<int (MP1Node::*)(void *, char *, int), MP1Node *>' to 'std::function<int (void *, char *, int)>'
```

Comment: If possible I recommend you take inspiration from the standard library when it uses callable objects: Use templates. Or instead of using `std::bind` use a  suitable lambda that calls `enqueueWrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `std::bind`, make it

```
std::bind(&MP1Node::enqueueWrapper,this,
    std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3)
```

Alternatively, use a lambda:

```
[this](void *env, char *buff, int size) { return enqueueWrapper(env, buff, size); }
```

(replace your `bind` call with the above).